# How to change auto single-column mobile(landscape mode) to display multiple columns (bootstrap 3)

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I have no issue with the single column layout in portrait mobile mode, but when viewing it on landscape mode it's just not balanced. I need the multiple columns to display in landscape mode in mobile. Before I just used `@media only screen and (min-width:500px) and (max-width:766px) {}`, but in Bootstrap I don't know how to override it. Any ideas?

Comment: Add your own media query for orientation, like `@media only screen and (min-width:500px) and (max-width:766px) and (orientation: portrait) { ... }` and `... and (orientation: landscape) { ... }`. Reference: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/media-queries-for-standard-devices/

Comment: Thanks for responding, will check this out, thanks!

Comment: By the way, may I ask is there a way to  somehow disable / overwrite the auto single-column for small devices(landscape orientation only), and make it adapt / inherit the orientation of the medium layout orientation based on the bootstrap settings? Thank you so much.

Comment: If you're referencing the CDN, you'll need to create a custom css file that does that. If you've downloaded the source to your server, you can just edit the bootstrap.css file directly and make the desired changes. Hope this helps.